# Postman Collection- Setting Authorization header through code

Tags: collections, header, postman, authorization, newman

Everytime I am testing postman collection ,I need to change the authorization token under header manually followed by exporting the collection again and running through newman.
Is there any way , instead of giving here, I can give it in a CSV file which is being used as test data file. which would reduce the efforts of changing code every time.
Please suggest.

Comment: there will be refresh token that you get which you can use to get new token by hitting the refresh end point

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, in your csv file, add one more column - name as "AT"
[image]

and mention that reference AT in your request as in the following picture.

[image]